# AWS lambda function not giving correct output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am new to python using boto3 for AWS. I am creating a lambda function that will return orphaned snapshots list. Code is -

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
    
    # Make a list of existing volumes
    all_volumes = ec2_resource.volumes.all()
    volumes = [volume.volume_id for volume in all_volumes]
    
    # Find snapshots without existing volume
    snapshots = ec2_resource.snapshots.filter(OwnerIds=['self'])
    
    # Create list of all snapshots
    osl =[]
    
    for snapshot in snapshots:
        if snapshot.volume_id not in volumes:
            osl.append(snapshot)
            print('\n Snapshot ID is :-    '+str(snapshot))
            #snapshot.delete()
            continue
        for tag in snapshot.tags:
          if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
              value=tag['Value']
              print('\n Snapshot Tags are:- '+str(tag))
              break
    print('Total orphaned snapshots are:-    '+str(len(osl)))
```

This returns list of snapshots & tags too in incorrect format.

[image]

Surprisingly, when I run same code in another account, it gives lambda function error -

[image]

I have created same permissions IAM role. But different results in different accounts is something i am not gettting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing `snapshot` object but you want to print `id`.
Second problem is all snapshot do not need to have `tags`, you need to check if snapshot have `tags` or not.

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
    
    # Make a list of existing volumes
    all_volumes = ec2_resource.volumes.all()
    volumes = [volume.volume_id for volume in all_volumes]
    
    # Find snapshots without existing volume
    snapshots = ec2_resource.snapshots.filter(OwnerIds=['self'])
    
    # Create list of all snapshots
    osl =[]
    
    for snapshot in snapshots:
        if snapshot.volume_id not in volumes:
            osl.append(snapshot.id)
            print('\n Snapshot ID is :-    ' + snapshot.id)
    for snapshot in snapshots:
        if snapshot.volume_id not in volumes:
            osl.append(snapshot.id)
            print('\n Snapshot ID is :-    ' + snapshot.id)
            if snapshot.tags:
                for tag in snapshot.tags:
                    if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
                        value = tag['Value']
                        print('\n Snapshot Tags are '+ tag['Key'] + ", value = " + value)
                        break
    print('Total orphaned snapshots are:-    '+str(len(osl)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe that id thing is what I missed. 

Also for  -- Second problem is all snapshot do not need to have tags, you need to check if snapshot have tags or not -> added else to print no tags. 

Next step to check how to print tags below the ID itself

Comment: You need to move tags condition under `volume` check, check my answer with updated version.